# Golang to informix DB connectivity issue

Tags: go, db2, informix

I am getting below error while connecting to Informix DB using Golang.

> Failed to load db2cli64.dll: The specified module could not be found.
> The go_ibm_db driver cannot be registered

The Informix DB I am trying to connect is on linux environment of our organization.

Below is the package I am following along

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/asifjalil/go_ibm_db#section-readme

Comment: Have you followed the [installation instructions](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db#readme-how-to-install-in-windows) (i.e. `go run setup.go`) and did that run successfully?

Comment: Yes I did. 

I am able to connect to DB from DBeaver (GUI) and DotNet but not from GoLang